# GCP GCE Establishing Cross Project VM SSH connections without a gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I have two private IP VMs, each are in two different projects, each have their own VPC with Private Google Access enabled and no VPC peering or a VPN tunnel between the two.

I am attempting to establish an SSH connection between each VM and cannot use gcloud commands since I am in a chroot. I can only use `ssh` commands. Since these VMs aren't in the same VPC, attempting to SSH to the IP address of the other instance would not work.

Could I somehow setup DNS records in Project A linking to the VM hostnames/private IPs in project B?

Comment: You cannot achieve your goal with only SSH. If the networks are not overlapping enable VPC peering. DNS will not help you. Private networks are just that - private. You will need a service to connect the networks together.

Comment: @JohnHanley Do you know what the mechanism is behind a gcloud ssh command working across projects without shared VPC or VPC peering? In the command you are able to declare an instance name, zone, and project ID. I was able to get this setup in a testing environment so more curious with understanding how the gcloud command works.

Comment: The service is Identity-Aware Proxy TCP Forwarding: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding

Comment: You can also use a bastion. the role of IAP, in fact

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the information. Seems like it is acceptable in our use case to setup VPC peering between these two projects so I'll look further into your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is by creating a Shared VPC network or a Cloud VPN. VPC peering won't work in this use-case because transitive peering is not supported.

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc

https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am actually attempting to use this to SSH from Instance A in project A to Instance B in project B. From what I've read it looks like VPC peering would work in that simple use case or am I mis-understanding? https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#example-setup

Comment: It won't hurt if you try. I've had issues connecting from one VM to another via SSH across different projects with VPC peering, that was my experience at least. Let us know if it worked.